# AlertDialog setItems with a list from room database: getValue() returns null

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

I'm simply trying to select from a list of Artists in my room database in an AlertDialog.  Calling getValue() on the LiveData object from the viewModel consistently gives me null.  Do I really need to make a ListAdapter for something this simple?!  Why is it so hard to get some strings from the database?

**ArtistDao**

```
@Dao
interface ArtistDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM artist_table")
    fun getAllArtists(): Flow<List<Artist>>

    @Query("SELECT name FROM artist_table")
    fun getArtistList(): Flow<List<String>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(artist: Artist)
}
```

**Menu Selection Option in Main Activity**

```
R.id.action_choose_artist -> {
            //create artist list
            val testList = songViewModel.artists.value
            val artistList = testList?.toTypedArray()

            // User chose choose artist action
            val alertDialog: AlertDialog? = this.let {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
                builder.apply {
                    setTitle(R.string.choose_artist)
                    setItems(artistList, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        artistName = artistList!![which]
                    })
                }
                // Create the AlertDialog
                builder.create()
            }
            alertDialog?.show()
            true
        }
```

**SongViewModel**

```
val artists: LiveData<List<String>> = repository.artists.asLiveData()
```

**SongRepository**

```
val artists: Flow<List<String>> = artistDao.getArtistList()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get `null` because nobody is observing your `Flow->LiveData`-chain. LiveData itself will only trigger and perform its work if somebody is observing it.

In your case I think you want a one-time request to receive the data from your DB and should use a suspend function and coroutines to achieve it. `Flow` in context of Room DB is only useful if you are interested in changes to the DB for this Query and want to react to it, e.g. by displaying the updated data in your `RecyclerView`.

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ArtistDao {
    @Query("SELECT name FROM artist_table")
    fun getArtistList(): List<String>
}
```

Repo:

```
suspend fun getArtistList(): List<String> = artistDao.getArtistList()
```

ViewModel:

```
fun getArtistList(onResult: (List<String>) -> Unit) {
  viewModelScope.launch{
      val artist = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){repository.getArtistList()}
      
      // maybe validate data, e.g. not empty

      onResult(artist)
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
R.id.action_choose_artist -> {
            //create artist list
            songViewModel.getArtistList { testList ->
                 val artistList = testList.toTypedArray()

                 // User chose choose artist action
                 ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you're suggesting that I do away with Flow entirely.  That makes sense to me as well because I don't need this particular menu to be dynamic but I ran into the problem that it was a database query on the main thread.  Are you attempting to solve that with the viewModelScope.launch?  I'm still not incredibly comfortable with all the lambdas in kotlin.

Comment: viewModelScope.launch starts a `Coroutine` which is bound to the lifecycle of the ViewModel. So when the ViewModel is cleared the coroutine is canceled. I forgot to add `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` around the repository call to make it run on the background thread. The result is then delivered with the callback on the MainThread. I updated my answer.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on with that?  I think I need to do something similar for getting a Song.  In the case of the song I need to pass the viewMoodel the name of the song I want to retrieve from the database.  I don't understand the function's signature.  Where is the input?  What would normally be the input looks like the onResult.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which function signature? Are you looking for something like this: `val song = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){repository.getSong(songName)}`

Comment: I tried doing something like that but it didn't work.  I was doing things on the main thread.  I ended up not needing to retrieve an individual song because I could just return it from the list.